# error at run "python draw_net.py"

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

```
    ezio@FM-NW-02:~/object_detection_5cls/caffe/python$ python draw_net.py ../examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt  lenet.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "draw_net.py", line 8, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "/home/ezio/object_detection_5cls/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/ezio/object_detection_5cls/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /home/ezio/object_detection_5cls/caffe/python/caffe/../../build/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3: undefined symbol: _ZNK7leveldb6Status8ToStringB5cxx11Ev
```

I have ran `make pycaffe; make all; make test; make runtest` and these are all passed. MNIST and CIFAR10 demo are also as expect.
but when I try to draw the net, an error occurred as above.
I installed `libleveldb` by `sudo apt-get install libleveldb-dev`
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have fixed this bug.

Just run `sudo python draw_net.py`

But something else wrong: `no module named google-protobuf` and `no module named skimage.io`

Then I used `sudo apt-get install python-protobuf` and `sudo apt-get install python-skimage` to install these packages

Back to `sudo python draw_net.py your_net.protobuf your_net.png`. An image file will be created in caffe_root/python folder